# JS difference between filename.js and ./filename.js

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me to understand,
What is difference between **filename.js** and **./filename.js**

(note: While we include in html or any js file)

Comment: @akhuntia -- can you show a few lines of code where you use the file name -- the correctness of the answer depends on where the filename is specified.

Comment: var moduleA = require("./module-a.js");
var moduleB = require("module-b.js");

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there are no differences: both point to the file named *filename.js* in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

filename.js refers to a js while residing in the current directory.
./filename.js means that in the current directory a filename.js resides.

So, basically there is no difference but when including, to give relative path you must use "./filnemae.js".

Answer (score 0):

Path can be relative or absolute. (./) means current directory, so if you are in a directory called test and you use ./page.js it means the full path is test/page.js

The second example page.js searches for a page with that name in the current directory.
Basically there are the same as long as you are referring to the file in same folder(test).

Answer (score 0):

there's no use is stating `"./filename.js"` over `"filename.js"`. It's a forgiven coding mistake more than a convention or a sort of standard. They will both create a (relative) path which will point to the [current directory]"filename.js".

I guess, what you are looking for is the `"../filename.js"` r.p. (relative path) syntax.

This is a shorthand and a correct syntax for r.p., pointing to the parent folder of the current path.

Let's say, your current path is:

`"domain/home/page1/index.html"`

adding `"../filename.js"` will produce:

`"domain/home/filename.js"`

whereas, `"filename.js"` will produce:

`"domain/home/page1/filename.js"`.